# 2012 ford focus battery drain

Tags: battery, drain

I Have 2012 ford focus 1.6 ti vct i recently encountered a battery drain and vehicle is making unusual noise in the dashboard on the passenger site. and i did send the vehicle to a dealer for scanning but they did not find any problem.
I did remove the fuses one by one and find that when i remove fuse25 10amp the noise stops and the battery does not drain when the fuse is off.

please assist what could be the problem that causes this battery drain. as i am currently driving my vehicle without that fuse. the fuse seems to be for Mirrors as per vehicle's manual but to my surprise mirrors are still working fine without that fuse.

Comment: Have a look on here  - there are many battery drain questions.

Comment: Is there a separate fuse for the mirror *heaters*?

Comment: Finding a wiring diagram would be the best way to trace it.